# Vectorized approach in pandas comparing two cumulative sums

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm currently iterating for this, but I'm looking to get the results in a vectorized manner and I'm drawing a blank. It's probably best to start with a DataFrame:

```
         actual_sum  expected_to_date           Late
id
1             11086             11086              0
1             22172             22172              0
1             33258             33258              0
1             33258             44344              1
1             33258             55430              2
1             33258             66516              3
1             33258             77602              4
1             33258             88688              5
3                 0             25748              1****
3                 0             51496              2
3                 0             77244              3
3                 0            102992              4
3                 0            128740              5
3                 0            154488              6
10005         19818             19818              0
10005         19818             39636              1
10005         59454             59454              0
10005         79272             79272              0
10005         79272             99090              1
10005         99090            118908              1
10005        118908            138726              1
10005        138726            158544              1
10005        164544            178362              1
10005        184362            198180              1
10005        184362            217998              2
10005        184362            237824              3
10006         26425             26425              0
10006         52850             52850              0
10006         79275             79275              0
10006         79275            105700              1
10006        132125            132125              0
10006        158550            158550              0
10006        158550            184975              1
10006        158550            211400              2
10006        158550            237825              3
10006        158550            264250              4
10006        158550            290666              5
10006        158550            317091              6
10009         21217             21217              0
10009         42434             42434              0
10009         63651             63651              0
```

So as you can see, here is what I'm doing:

- If actual_sum and expected_to_date are equal, put a 0
- If expected is > actual, then grab the last time that expected was <= our current actual_sum **within the same id**, and take the difference in periods of the two.
- This is done on a per id basis. So check out #3. The very first one
  has a difference, so it is immediately Late by 1.

Any ideas on a vectorized approach to something like this? I can't think of anything. Currently most of my code time is spent on finding the last time within this id that we have something less than our current actual_sum:

```
last_current = d[(d.id==cur_id)&(d.expected_to_date > cur_sum)][:idx]
```

I have to add 1 to this result to get what I want, but it does work.

Comment: By periods here "take the difference in periods of the two", which column are you referring to ?

Comment: Purely count. You can see in the Late column what it is doing. The actual-sum and expected_to_date are equal and the Late is 0. If they aren't equal, then the last time that expected was >= the current row, the Late column should be the difference in rows between the two. You could imagine a Helper column of df['Helper'] = range(0,len(df)) and use the difference in the helper column for this difference.

Comment: I don't think this will vectorize as you need to check n-back, if it were just reseting each time it would be possible. I think I'd just drop to cython.

Answer (score 0):

I think this comes close to what you want ... it does not get rid of every for-loop ... but it reduces the number ... the data is in a DataFrame called df ...

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)   # get a unique index
df['ones'] = 1  # temp column of ones (for use in cumulative sum)
df['Later'] = 0 # this is where our result will be put 
for label, group in df.groupby('id'):
    # for each group select cases and number them from 1 using cumsum()
    df['Later'].update(group[group.expected_to_date > group.actual_sum]
        ['ones'].cumsum())
del df['ones']  # remove temporary working column
df.set_index('id', inplace=True) # restore original index
```

Which yields ...

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]: 
       actual_sum  expected_to_date   Late  Later
id                                               
1           11086             11086      0      0
1           22172             22172      0      0
1           33258             33258      0      0
1           33258             44344      1      1
1           33258             55430      2      2
1           33258             66516      3      3
1           33258             77602      4      4
1           33258             88688      5      5
3               0             25748  1****      1
3               0             51496      2      2
3               0             77244      3      3
3               0            102992      4      4
3               0            128740      5      5
3               0            154488      6      6
10005       19818             19818      0      0
10005       19818             39636      1      1
10005       59454             59454      0      0
10005       79272             79272      0      0
10005       79272             99090      1      2
10005       99090            118908      1      3
10005      118908            138726      1      4
10005      138726            158544      1      5
10005      164544            178362      1      6
10005      184362            198180      1      7
10005      184362            217998      2      8
10005      184362            237824      3      9
10006       26425             26425      0      0
10006       52850             52850      0      0
10006       79275             79275      0      0
10006       79275            105700      1      1
10006      132125            132125      0      0
10006      158550            158550      0      0
10006      158550            184975      1      2
10006      158550            211400      2      3
10006      158550            237825      3      4
10006      158550            264250      4      5
10006      158550            290666      5      6
10006      158550            317091      6      7
10009       21217             21217      0      0
10009       42434             42434      0      0
10009       63651             63651      0      0
```

For completeness, this is how I got your data into a dataframe called df ...

```
data="""id       actual_sum  expected_to_date           Late
1             11086             11086              0
1             22172             22172              0
1             33258             33258              0
1             33258             44344              1
1             33258             55430              2
1             33258             66516              3
1             33258             77602              4
1             33258             88688              5
3                 0             25748              1****
3                 0             51496              2
3                 0             77244              3
3                 0            102992              4
3                 0            128740              5
3                 0            154488              6
10005         19818             19818              0
10005         19818             39636              1
10005         59454             59454              0
10005         79272             79272              0
10005         79272             99090              1
10005         99090            118908              1
10005        118908            138726              1
10005        138726            158544              1
10005        164544            178362              1
10005        184362            198180              1
10005        184362            217998              2
10005        184362            237824              3
10006         26425             26425              0
10006         52850             52850              0
10006         79275             79275              0
10006         79275            105700              1
10006        132125            132125              0
10006        158550            158550              0
10006        158550            184975              1
10006        158550            211400              2
10006        158550            237825              3
10006        158550            264250              4
10006        158550            290666              5
10006        158550            317091              6
10009         21217             21217              0
10009         42434             42434              0
10009         63651             63651              0
"""
from StringIO import StringIO # import from io for Python 3
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0, index_col=0, sep='\s+')
```